# Python: Find the name of the columns where NA values are above a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, na, threshold

I know how to drop columns with many NA from a data frame,

```
df = df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=100)
```

But is there a way to know their names?

I though to create something like this:

```
na_values =  df.isnull().sum()/len(df)
```

Which gives me a list with the portion of NA within each columns

```
x_9       0.011700
x_10      0.001307
x_11      0.025830
x_12      0.011691
x_13      0.002739
x_14      0.238406
```

But I want to extract only the ones that have above a 0.2 threshold, like x_14.

Any ideas? I tried:

```
print(i > 0.4 for i in na_values)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: you can just do `na_values[na_values > 0.2]`

Comment: I didn't even know about that. Thanks! Quite new you see

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried to do that but it doesn't let me until some time has passed. So I returned back to my code and I was planning to mark the question as answered later. Thanks for the answer and the reminder though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same `Series` with a boolean condition to mask the Series:

```
In [36]:
na_values[na_values>0.2]

Out[36]:
            na
val           
x_14  0.238406
```

You can see the mask:

```
In [37]:
na_values > 0.2

Out[37]:
val
x_9     False
x_10    False
x_11    False
x_12    False
x_13    False
x_14     True
Name: na, dtype: bool
```

so this will mask out all the `False` rows